# Laravel API: oath/token returns bad request

Tags: php, api, oauth, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I'm trying to learn how to make an API in laravel 5.5, I installed passport for user authentication, then:

Added: 
    `Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,` To "config/app.php"

Added: 
    `use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;`
    and
    `use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;`
To "App/User.php"

Made the migrations successfully and runned "php artisan passport:install"

Added:
    `use Laravel\Passport\Passport;`
    and `Passport::routes();` to the boot function
in "AuthServiceProvider"

Also changed the api driver to "passport" in "config/auth.php"

But when i try to make a post request in "localhost/laravel_api/oauth/token"
it returns a bad request as seen below:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9wrZ.jpg)

in the headers i use:
Accept : application/json,
Content-Type: application/json

What's the cause of the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing to do with Laravel, Passport, etc. This is your webserver's 404 page, not Laravel's, which means your server isn't configured to pass `laravel_api/oauth/token` to the Laravel app. Check your server config.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

There is an issue using xampp. I runned "php artisan serve" and used "http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token"

Does anyone know how to work with xampp without this problem?

Comment: You need to configure XAMPP properly to send requests to the Laravel app.

Answer (score -1):

Have you registered URL in routes/api.php file?
Also Laravel adds api to urls automatically so you have to take care of that too.

Comment: I can see the route when i type "php artisan route:list", i didn't add it in the api.php file. Should i still add it?

Comment: OP would be getting a Laravel 404 page, not Apache, if it were a routing issue.